# Robots.txt file to allow all root php files except one and disallow all subfolders content

Tags: robots.txt

I seem to be struggling with a robots.txt file in the following scenario.  I would like all root folder *.php files to be indexed except for one (exception.php) and would like all content from all subdirectories of the root folder not to be indexed.

I have tried the following, but it allows accessing php files in subdirectories even though subdirectories in general are not indexed?

....

```
# robots.txt 
User-agent: *
Allow: /*.php
disallow: /*
disallow: /exceptions.php
```

....

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For crawlers that interpret `*` in `Disallow` values as wildcard (it’s not part of the robots.txt spec, but many crawlers support it anyway), this should work:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /exceptions.php
Disallow: /*/
```

This disallows URLs like:

- `https://example.com/exceptions.php`
- `https://example.com//`
- `https://example.com/foo/`
- `https://example.com/foo/bar.php`

And it allows URLs like:

- `https://example.com/`
- `https://example.com/foo.php`
- `https://example.com/bar.html`

---

For crawlers that don’t interpret `*` in `Disallow` values as wildcard, you would have to list all subfolders (on the first level):

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /exceptions.php
Disallow: /foo/
Disallow: /bar/
```